# How to manually create a class with a configuration for testing

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a class that I use in playframework that automatically injects the dependency.

How can I create this class "manually" in my test code:

```
class AppConfog @Inject()(c: Configuration) {
   val supportEmail = c.getString("app.email").get
   ...
}
```

I'm not sure how to get a Configuration class to pass into it.

I know I can create an inline config like:

```
  val config =
    """
    akka {
      loglevel = "WARNING"
    }
    """

  ConfigFactory.parseString(config)
```

How do I get a Configuration from a config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Play's `Configuration` just wraps Typesafe `Config` that you get with your `ConfigFactory.parseString(config)`. See [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.15/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala#L174).
So you should be able to do this:

```
val underlying =  ConfigFactory.parseString(config)
val configuration = Configuration(underlying)
val mockAppConfog = new AppConfog(configuration)
```